# Keras, Score v.s Predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm currently training a Keras model for classification (20 classes), text classification problem.

When I train the model with a training and validation set, I get an output like this:

> Epoch 19/20 59500/59500 [==============================] - 22s
>   371us/step - loss: 0.0038 - accuracy: 0.9989 - val_loss: 0.6645 -
>   val_accuracy: 0.9550

Suggesting a very good validation accuracy. Afterwards, when I call my model to evaluate the score (on the *same* validation set) I get:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(f"Keras Score: {classifier.score(X_test, valid_labels)}")
print(f"Accuracy on test set: {100 * accuracy_score(np.argmax(valid_labels, axis=1),    predictions):.2f}%")
```

Yielding:

> 10500/10500 [==============================] - 1s 66us/step
>   10500/10500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step 
>   Keras Score: 0.9546093940734863
>   Accuracy on test set: 49.58%

I expected the scores to be exactly the same, since it is the same data, the same measure and everything. The labels are encoded as one-hot vectors, thus the argmax in the accuracy calculation.

I would of course like the achieve the performance the model seems to be having while training, I am simply confused as to why the performance is not even the same. While I understand the model might not be correct, I don't understand why the model predicts something different than what it uses to calculate the score (metrics is accuracy).

The model is trained with:

```
history = classifier.fit(X_train, train_labels,
                    epochs=20,
                    verbose=True,
                    validation_data=(X_test, valid_labels),
                    batch_size=20)
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Predictions returned by the model are not a one-hot vector. They are an integer that I believe is the class predicted.

Comment: Please show the definition of your `classifier` model and your  `classifier.compile` statement; can't see at present how you get predictions of shape `(N, )`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the loss function was incorrect for a multiclass classification problem. Changing it and retraining yielded consistent results across both the validation data provided for training and my own test set.

Answer (score 1):

Is your predictions (N,20) numpy array? Judging from your labels, `y`, being one-hot encoded, I would expect prediction for a sample `x` to be also a vector with probabilities for every category (20 in this case).

If this is the case;

```
accuracy_score(np.argmax(valid_labels, axis=1), np.argmax(predictions, axis=1))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I edited the question; the shape of the predictions is (N,)